# What are exceptions and how they will be raised in pipeline

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

Hi I am not sure what is exception here and how it will be raised in following case 

`Sub $11,$2,$4
And $12,$2,$5
Or $13, $2,$6
Add $1,$2,$1
Slt $15,$6,$7`

I was reading and encountered that

 `add $1,$2,$1`

will cause an exception. Could you guys please help in understanding what is exception here.

Comment: You should put a little more context. As is, such arith./logic instructions as add, sub, or, don't trigger exceptions. Maybe an external event is causing an interrupt (IRQ) or this is a MMU fault.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Where did you read the statement that that `add` instruction will cause an exception?  What's the context, and what was the book/resource that made that claim?

Comment: Wild guess: it's assembly for MIPS (popular architecture in lectures, MIPS has an `slt` instruction and has 3 operands instructions) and the `add` of MIPS has a trap/interrupt/exception (I'm not up to date with MIPS nomemclature) on overflow (it has an `addu` which doesn't trap on overflow).  So the surrounding text should explain why add is excepted to overflow, perhaps by giving the initial values of used registers.